# Does Zero Point energy imply acceleration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Since there cannot be zero momentum in QM systems do such things as [Zitterbewegung](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zitterbewegung) imply accelerations?

Comment: See [Is Zitterbewegung an artefact of single-particle theory?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28672/is-zitterbewegung-an-artefact-of-single-particle-theory). Zitterbewegung is not to be taken literally as the particle vibrating to and fro.

Comment: However, there is still zero point motion in other systems due to the uncertainty principle. Does that involve accelerations? Or only on measurement?

Comment: Re the *close as duplicate* vote, Dirk's question is clearly broader than just Zitterbewegung, so the question [Is Zitterbewegung an artefact of single-particle theory?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28672/is-zitterbewegung-an-artefact-of-single-particle-theory) is not a duplicate.

Comment: Forget Zitterbewegung. It's about motion of particles in lowest energy states, including (say) liquid helium.

Comment: Dirk, I'm not sure your question as sense, as I suspect you are still thinking about the oscillator as if it was a classical particle. If you express a SHO in momentum space then the ground state is something like $\Phi(p,t) = A \exp(-p^2/2\hbar m \omega - i\omega t/2)$ so it's not a momentum eigenstate, but the momentum isn't changing in any oscilliatory way as it would in a pendulum.