# Antimatter: Dirac's Sea Interpretation or Feynman's Backward in Time Interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, feynman-diagrams, antimatter, dirac-equation

I know that these are the 2 interpretations about antiparticles, hypothesized to handle negative solutions to *energy multiplied with time*.

1. What are the superiorities and drawbacks of each, compared to the
   other?
2. Adopting the principle that each solution represents some part of
   reality, can these 2 interpretations be real for some
   (anti)particles in nature, coming from the positive solution (as
   neg*neg=pos)?

Then we would have 4 states for (anti)particles comprising all of the quadrants:

- positive energy positive time
- positive energy negative time
- negative energy positive time
- negative energy negative time

Comment: Related questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/is-anti-matter-matter-going-backwards-in-time?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19378/what-was-missing-in-diracs-argument-to-come-up-with-the-modern-interpretation-o?rq=1).

Comment: You can use either picture but you can't use both; there are not 4 types of matter/antimatter.

Comment: Why not? How do we know or test that time is positive for all the matter?

Answer (score 1):

Steven Weinberg in his “The Quantum Theory of Fields” states that charged bosons such as W+- particles, which do not obey an exclusion principle, have nothing preventing them from falling into negative energy states whether these states are occupied or not.  This is a serious problem for the Dirac sea model.  Weinberg then quotes Julian Schwinger:  “The picture of an infinite sea of negative energy electrons is now best regarded as a historical curiosity, and forgotten.”