# What is negative energy as used by Dirac to explain pair production?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, pair-production

While reading about pair production, I came across the concept of negative energy. What is negative energy exactly? And can there be negative mass corresponding to this energy?

Comment: Can you give a reference to where you were reading this?

Comment: Quantum Physics of Atoms, Molecules, Solids, Nuclei, and Particles

Book by Robert Martin Eisberg and Robert Resnick

Comment: Its a pretty lengthy explanation as how Dirac explained pair production by considering the negative possibility of energy combining quantum mechanics and relativity. Please read it.

Comment: @my2cts Take a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19378/what-was-missing-in-diracs-argument-to-come-up-with-the-modern-interpretation-o and related questions on the Dirac sea.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thanks, interesting discussion. In my opinion the answers there are an interesting record of how the physics community was and still is wrestling with this. Also in my opinion the concern remains that Dirac theory predicts negative energy, for either matter of for antimatter, and that the Dirac Hamiltonian commutation with position x does not produce p/m but the nonsensical result of c.

Comment: Corrected: How does this book explain the positive energy and mass of the positron?

Comment: @Mechanic7 I don't own a copy. I have a lot of textbooks on the subject but not this one. Hence it would help me if you could outline the argument. I am curious how this lingering matter is dealt with in present university courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matter and antimatter have positive energy and mass. Both the electron and the positron have a positive rest energy of 511 keV and a positive mass of $9.11\times 10^{-31} $ kg.

In my opinion the concern remains that Dirac theory predicts negative energy, for either matter of for antimatter, and that the Dirac Hamiltonian commutation with position x does not produce p/m but the nonsensical result of c.

In spite of it being wholly unphysical the concept of a bottomless Dirac sea of filled electron states is still entertained in modern textbooks like Reinhardt Quantum Mechanics 3ed (2003), even with a picture at page 382. It would be sarcasm to ask whether this Dirac sea becomes superconducting at low temperature.