# Does the positron prove that Dirac's electron sea must exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, antimatter, dirac-equation

Does the fact that the positron exists in cosmic rays prove the existence of Dirac' s 'sea' of spin-paired electrons in space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was missing in Dirac's argument to come up with the modern interpretation of the positron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19378/)

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not, because the "sea" was an idea, not the solution.

Comment: Ok, so what was the solution?

Comment: The operator solution for $\psi$ contained electrons and positrons on an equal footing. The actual occupation numbers of these particles are dictated with the initial (or boundary, or experimental) conditions which is the only right way to look at this problem.

Comment: Ok, I was talking more about the practicalities of them showing up in cosmic rays and whether or not it's physical to think of such a sea producing them.