# How can the ground state charge be renormalized?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, vacuum, ground-state

When we calculate the total charge and energy of a quantum field by using Noether's theorem, we find that they are infinitely large, even if we consider a finite spacetime volume_
$$H  =  \int_V \mathrm{d }k^3  \frac{\omega_k}{(2\pi)^3 }   a^\dagger(\vec k) a(\vec k)+ \frac{1}{2} \int_V \mathrm{d }k^3  \omega_k  \delta(\vec 0)  \, . $$
 It it sometimes [argued](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19381/37286) that these infinite contribution can be removed by renormalizing the ground state charge and energy.

Often this problem is dealt with by normal ordering the Hamiltonian. But I was wondering if it is also possible to introduce a bare ground state charge $Q_0$  and energy $E_0$ that allows us to absorb the infinite contributions by setting the value of the measurable ground state charge and energy to the observed value (zero)
$$ Q \equiv Q_0 + C \int_V \delta(0) =0 \, . $$
$$ E \equiv E_0 + \tilde{C} \int_V \delta(0) =0 \, . $$
This would be a lot more similar to how we usually renormalize but I'm struggling to understand where exactly $Q_0$, $E_0$ appear in the theory.

Usually, the bare parameters are equal to parameters in the Lagrangian. This suggests that there areadditional term in the Lagrangian 
$$ \mathcal{L} = \ldots + Q_0 \times ? + E_0 \times ?$$ 
that yields  constant contribution to the Noether charges. For example, instead of the formula given above for the Hamiltonian we find
$$H  =  \int_V \mathrm{d }k^3  \frac{\omega_k}{(2\pi)^3 }   a^\dagger(\vec k) a(\vec k)+ \frac{1}{2} \int_V \mathrm{d }k^3  \omega_k  \delta(\vec 0) + E_0  \, . $$
This could be used to renormalize the ground state energy and charge as described above.

---

*Does this kind of approach make sense? And if yes, is it discussed in more explicit terms somewhere?*

Comment: Noether currents (such as the energy-momentum tensor or the current density) are always defined up to a closed form, so you can always let $j\to j+\mathrm d\chi$. This induces a change $Q\to Q+\int\chi$, which is precisely the counter-term you are after. Noether's procedure will never fix $j$ uniquely: a boundary term $\mathrm d\chi$ is always allowed by the construction, and is completely arbitrary.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Awesome, thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for. Your comment reminded me of this fantastic paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03616 which, I think, discusses exactly what you describe